# Como mostrar una imagen cargada en mi proyecto LARAVEL

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

hice un metodo para cargar una imagena  mi base de datos por medio de un formulario, y en la base de datos se almacena una direccion, ahora busco como mostrarla, he intentado un par de cosas pero no me dieron resultado.

Este es el controlador donde envio la imagen a la base de datos y se almacena en mi servidor local igual, ya corrobore y ahi estan las imagenes

```
 public function save(Request $request){
        $data2= Questions::all();
        $validator=$this->validate($request,[
            'Sede'=>'required',
            'Alcance'=>'required',
            'Nombre'=>'required',
            'Cierre'=>'required',
            'Areas'=>'required',
            
        ]); 

            $imagen = $request->file('urlfoto');
            $nombre = time().'.'.$imagen->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destino = public_path('images');
            $request->urlfoto->move($destino, $nombre);



        $request->merge([ 
            'Areas' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('Areas')),
            'preguntas' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('preguntas'))
            ]);
        $user=Project::create($request->all());
        return back()->with(compact('data2'))->with('datosGuardados', 'Datos almacenados, Correctamente')->with(compact('data2'));
    }
```

AQUI quiero imprimir la imagen

```
@foreach($data as $project)

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            <img src="{{$project->urlfoto}}" alt="">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que se puedan ver las imágenes el servidor web tiene que poder mostraras, por lo que deben estar en la carpeta public. Normalmente los archivos subidos por usuarios estan en la carpeta storage, para crear un enlace de la carpeta storage en public puedes ejecutar [php artisan storage:link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

Dicho esto una vez que quieras recuperrar el archivo puedes crear una url  usando `asset` ej. `echo asset('storage/file.txt');` o en tu caso `echo asset($project->urlfoto);`

Toda la documentacion ofical sobre el sistema de archivos de laravel [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Para guardan una imagen puedes hacer uso del metodo store `$path = $request->file('photo')->store('public\imagenes');` Como dije anteriormente laravel guarda los archivos en storage, por lo que la ruta de la imagen subida sera storage\public\imagenes\nombre_de_la_imagen.extension

Por defecto el metodo `store` genera un hash unico para cada imagen/archivo (Para añadirle el nombre deseado puede usar [storeAs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name)

Por ultimo quedaria añadir la ruta al campo en la base de datos. Puede guardar la ruta absoluta (`$path` en este caso) o guardar unicamente el nombre usando la funcion `basename($path)`.

Si usa esta ultima opcion a la hora de mostrar la imagen debera especificar la ruta de directorios (`asset('/storage/imagenes/'.$foo->photo`)

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/C:\xampp\tmp\php4CE0.tmp se me imprime esto

Comment: y solo aparece el logo de imagen pero no carga correctemente

Comment: @salvagarcia entonces creo que estas guardando mal la ruta en la base de datos. ahora actualizo la respuesta para mostrarte como suelo guardar yo una imagen con laravel

Comment: Si, ya me funciono, gracias